Trying to get playonlinux working - asyncore module missing?
So I'm pretty new to Ubuntu (Ubuntu 24.04 LST, noble) and I'm trying to get playonlinux working, but it crashes every time I try to start it (I click the icon and it doesn't open and then I sometimes get a crash report). I've checked and winbind and playonlinux both appear to be properly installed. When I try run playonlinux from terminal it gives a module not found error and says:
'No module named 'asyncore''
I've tried to search up online how to fix this, but the one thing I found that suggested how to fix it didn't work. Any tips?
Thanks for the help :)

Brand new OS only a few weeks old. Did you inquire of the vendors of the apps they work with this new version of Ubuntu?

I haven't, but you're right, maybe that's the issue. I literally only got running with ubuntu like a week ago, so that might be something if there's been a new version come in. Is it worth just waiting a while and seeing if the ap updates and catches up?

I would still contact the vendor of the app or at least see if they have a forum and find out is Ubuntu 24.04 is supported.

My issue has solved with installing below package:
sudo apt-get install python3-pyasyncore

My Linux version is Ubuntu 24.04 Noble.

I installed 'python3-pyasyncore' package with apt and solved it.

The requirement for the Python asyncore module is a mistake in the PlayOnLinux code which has been corrected about 14 days after this question was raised; see the merged pull request https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4/pull/73 for details. Practically, it's enough to remove the line from asyncore import dispatcher from python/options.py. Installing the package python3-pyasyncore, as other answers suggest, addresses only the effect, not the cause.
